# How to integrate pagination

Tags: angular, pagination

How to incorporate pagination in existing Angular 2 website?

Comment: What have you tried, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: <ul>
     <li *ngFor = "let datainfos of datainfo"> {{datainfos.name}}</li>
    </ul> 
      

       <pagination [boundaryLinks]="true" [totalItems]="totalItems" [(ngModel)]="currentPage" class="pagination-sm"
           previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;"></pagination>

Comment: export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  datainfo:any;
  public totalItems: number = 64;
 public currentPage: number = 4;
 public smallnumPages: number = 0;

 public setPage(pageNo: number): void {
   this.currentPage = pageNo;
 }

 public pageChanged(event: any): void {
   console.log('Page changed to: ' + event.page);
   console.log('Number items per page: ' + event.itemsPerPage);
 }

Comment: Please find consolidated source code . How to incorporate pagination

Comment: How to implement Pagination to display data

Comment: [Edit] the question, stop just saying the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer bootstrap pagination Or PrimeNG pagination.I am using PrimeNG pagination with my Angular2 app with RC5 version.

Comment: How to implement Pagination to display data